# Which town or village in Britain lost the greatest percentage of men in WWI due to "Pals Battalions"?

Tags: war, world-war-one, britain, battle, death

The British decision to create "Pals Battalions" of men from a single town or village led to unanticipated disasters when  Pals battalions  ran into heavy resistance, with large numbers of men from a single town or village being killed in a single day.

Which town or village lost the greatest percentage of its men in such a disaster?

Answer (score 9):

This question is addressed in this article:

[Tragedy of the lost generation](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3927026/Tragedy-lost-generation-Map-shows-towns-cities-WWI-wiped-tens-thousands-people-including-circles-friends-Britain-left-scarred-forever.html)

It concludes that Durham had the highest percentage loss, with 6353 dead representing nearly 8% of the city's population.

[image]